# Android: limit the number of notifications in notification bar

Tags: android, push-notification, broadcastreceiver, google-cloud-messaging

I created simple android application and it integrated with push notifications. Push notifications are working properly but now i want to limit the number of notifications which shown in the list (maximum 5). when user gets the 6th one, want to remove oldest one. i go through the web but i can't find a way to implement this thing.

1. Is it possible to implement this scenario ?

this is my GCM Intent service,

```
@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);
    // The getMessageType() intent parameter must be the intent you received
    // in your BroadcastReceiver.
    String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);
    // Log.e(getPackageName(), messageType);
    if (!extras.isEmpty()) {
        if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_SEND_ERROR.equals(messageType)) {
            // sendNotification("Send error: " + extras.toString());
        } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_DELETED.equals(messageType)) {
            // sendNotification("Deleted messages on server: " +
            // extras.toString());
            // If it's a regular GCM message, do some work.
        } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_MESSAGE.equals(messageType)) {
            // Post notification of received message.
            // newms = extras.getString("message").toString();
            sendNotification(extras.getString("title"), extras.getString("id"));
            ;
        }
    }
    GcmBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
}

private void sendNotification(String title, String id) {

    mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("title", title);
    intent.putExtra("id", id);

    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    Uri uri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.pqr)
            .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.app_name)).setSound(uri).setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(title))
            .setContentText(title);

    mBuilder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL);
    mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
    mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
    mNotificationManager.notify(Integer.parseInt(id), mBuilder.build());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes we can implement this. I saved locally push notification ids and cleared 1st id when 6th one came.(for that we can use queue.)